# Replace definition of built-in function in R?

Tags: r, function, package

The 'sparcl' package uses the 'kmeans' function in the standard 'stat' package. I want to make it use my own implementation of kmeans++ instead.

One way to do this would be to edit the code in the sparcl package itself. I'd prefer to avoid this, both because it would be messy and because I'm not sure how I would then install that edited code in R.

Unfortunately, the superassignment operator "<<-" doesn't work:

```
> kmeans <<- function(x) print("hi!")
Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'kmeans'
```

neither does "assign":

```
assign("kmeans",function(x) {print("HI THERE!"); return(FALSE)},pos="package:sparcl")
Error in assign("is.null", function(x) { : 
  cannot add bindings to a locked environment
```

So is editing the package code the only way?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use `trace` for this?

Comment: What is the reason you want to replace the old one instead of just writing a new version and using that one instead?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create your own version of the (exported) function that calls `kmeans` and alter those instances so that they call your own custom function? (Maybe that's what @Dason was saying as well...?)

Comment: I vote for @joran's suggestion. And if you do want to package up the function, do so by creating your own mini-package (that perhaps imports from stats) rather than by editing the stats package's source code!

Comment: @joran's suggestion isn't quite perfect, since `kmeans` is called multiple times in multiple functions in multiple files in the sparcl package, so I'd have to copy and edit all those as well... But that's how I was planning to do it initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further thought (and after re-reading your question), here's a simple solution that should work for you.

All you need to do is to assign your edited version of `kmeans()` to the symbol `kmeans` in the global environment.  In other words, at the command line do this:

```
kmeans <- function(...) plot(rnorm(99), col="red") # but using your own edits

## Then run an example from ?KMeansSparseCluster to see that it works.
library(sparcl)
x <- matrix(rnorm(50*300),ncol=300)
x[1:25,1:50] <- x[1:25,1:50]+1
x <- scale(x, TRUE, TRUE)
KMeansSparseCluster.permute(x,K=2,wbounds=seq(3,9,len=15),nperms=5)
```

This works because `KMeansSparseCluster()` (and calls to any other functions in `package:sparcl`) look for `kmeans` *first* in `namespace:sparcl`, *then* in `imports:sparcl`, *then* in `namespace:base`, and then in `.GlobalEnv`, where it'll find your redefined `kmeans` before it gets to the one in `package:stats`. To have a look yourself, try this:

```
parent.env(asNamespace("sparcl"))
parent.env(parent.env(asNamespace("sparcl")))
parent.env(parent.env(parent.env(asNamespace("sparcl"))))
## etc., also wrapping any of the environments above in calls to ls() 
## to see what's in 'em
```

Nicely, functions from the stats package that use `kmeans()` won't be disrupted by your version, because they will find `kmeans` in their own namespace, before the symbol-search ever gets to the global environment.

Comment: @JoshOBrien: Isn't it possible that the package specifically imports `kmeans` from the stats package, so it would be in `imports:sparcl`?  That would be the "Right" way to do it, yes?

Comment: @Aaron -- I agree: it would be the right way to do it, but it's not what sparcl's author(s) did. I checked `imports:sparcl`, and it's empty. Your larger point is a good one, though. This solution wouldn't work if the package authors had put `import("stats")` in their NAMESPACE file.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Josh.  Nice thinking to check what was in `imports:sparcl`.

Answer (score 7):

If you do want to edit a function's body (but not its arguments) during an interactive session, you can use `trace()`, like this:

```
trace("kmeans", edit=TRUE)
```

Then, in the editor that pops up, edit the body, so that it looks like this (for example):

```
function (x, centers, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1, algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong", 
"Lloyd", "Forgy", "MacQueen")) 
{
    plot(rnorm(99), col = "red")
}
```

Save the edited function definition and then exit the editor.

Back at the R command line, you can view the edited function and try it out:

```
body(kmeans)  # To view the tracing code
kmeans()      # To use the edited function
```

Finally, to revert to the unedited function, just do `untrace("kmeans")`. (I generally prefer using `trace()` to `assignInNamespace()` and friends because `untrace()` makes it so easy to undo changes.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about trace(). Though I don't think it completely solves my problem because of the large number of calls the sparcl package makes to kmeans in different functions...

Comment: @martas Maybe just grab the source code for the package, with a good text editor altering all instances of `kmeans` calls won't take too much time, and then rebuild the package locally. I think folks are just a bit leery of a solution that involves overwriting the stats package code itself, which you might regret later.

Comment: `trace()` edits the function in  `namespace:stats`, so it will edit the version of the `kmeans()` seen by any function that calls it. Isn't that what you want, or am I confused? (Not mutually exclusive possibilities, I know...)

Comment: Mother of god, it (your edit) works! Thank you. I suppose this works because kmeans isn't part of a package the sparcl code explicitly imported, right? I'm still very ignorant about the way R handles namespaces...

Comment: @martas -- Oops. You may want to move the 'Accept' over to my other answer. (I decided it was so much different than the previous answer that I should split it up. I would have overwritten the previous answer re: trace, but it looks like it may be useful on its own.)