# User defined colour palette in R and ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use another color palette for the scatter plots from `ggpairs` from the `GGally` library in R. See [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711550/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-palette-for-ggally-ggpairs-using-ggplot).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
```

**Works**

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf() + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")
```

[image: ggplot2_1]

**Also works**

```
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf()
```

[image: ggplot2_2]

**Does not work**

```
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")

ggpairs(iris, 
    columns=, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
    colour='Species',
    lower=list(continuous='points'), 
    axisLabels='none',  
    upper=list(continuous='blank')
)
```

[image: ggpairs1]
but adding

```
putPlot(p, ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), 1,1)
```

adds a plot in the right colors.

[image: ggpairs2]

**Workaround**

I can change the plots afterwards with getPlot, but that's not pretty..

```
subplot <- getPlot(a, 2, 1) # retrieve the top left chart
subplotNew <- subplot + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")
a <- putPlot(a, subplotNew, 2, 1)
```

How can I change the color scheme for the scatter plots in ggpairs? More specifically, I'd like to manually define the colors like so

```
scale_colour_manual(values=c("#FF0000","#000000", "#0000FF","#00FF00"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi you could store your `ggpairs` plot in an object, say `gg` and modify `gg$plots`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hack that works:

```
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")
unlockBinding("ggplot",parent.env(asNamespace("GGally")))
assign("ggplot",ggplot,parent.env(asNamespace("GGally")))
```

When you assign a new value to the `ggplot` function, it is in the global environment. Now, `GGally` imports everything including `ggplot` when it loads (it didn't have to be that way). At that point, changing the `ggplot` function in your global environment has no effect, because imports from `GGally` have precedence. Instead, you need to update the `ggplot` function on the `GGally:imports`. There is only one problem: once a package is loaded, its bindings are locked. But we can unlock them (I am guessing this is frowned upon, hence labeling the solution a hack).

See Josh O'Brien's answer under [Replace definition of built-in function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748716/replace-definition-of-built-in-function-in-r) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

as [stacksia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871942/4438664) said (but also adding scale_fill_brewer)

```
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral")
unlockBinding("ggplot",parent.env(asNamespace("GGally")))
assign("ggplot",ggplot,parent.env(asNamespace("GGally")))
```

See Josh O'Brien's answer under [Replace definition of built-in function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748716/replace-definition-of-built-in-function-in-r) for more info.