# Changing labels in pair-plot?

Tags: r, correlation, facet-grid

I'm using `pairs()` to create a correlations plot and am trying to show labels on the side and bottom instead of the diagonal panel but can't seem to find a way to do it

```
library(colorspace)
x <- matrix(rnorm(120 * 5), ncol = 5)
col <- (rainbow_hcl(2))[c(rep(1, 60), rep(2, 60))]
pairs(x, col = col, lower.panel = NULL, cex.labels = 2, pch = 19, cex = 0.8, cex.axis = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I can imagine you could do it using [tag:ggplot2], [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731111/1305688) is something that you might be able to use if you would take that route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User defined colour palette in R and ggpairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237783/user-defined-colour-palette-in-r-and-ggpairs)